# Grafana API - How to delete dashboards in multiple organisations together?

Tags: node.js, grafana, dashboard

I have a dashboard in 4 organisations with the same title and `uid`.
I want to delete a dashboard all 4 organisations together through grafana API.

How can I achieve this?